# How to get String output variables with FMPy?

Tags: python, fmi

I'm using FMPy to simulate some FMUs which have String output variables, yet these are not available in the simulation results (object returned by simulate_fmu(filename)).

Are these variables handled in a different way? If so, how can I access them?

Thank you.

## Edit 1:

I runned a simulation using [values.fmu](https://github.com/qtronic/fmusdk/tree/master/fmu20/src/models/values) which has a String output variable (`string_out`).

### Minimal example:

```
import fmpy
# fmu path
fmu_name = "C:\\fmusdk\\fmu20\\fmu\\cs\\x64\\values.fmu"
# Simulate
res = fmpy.simulate_fmu(fmu_name, stop_time=2., debug_logging=False)
# Results
print('Results names and types: ' + str(res.dtype))
```

Note: to run the example you have to download and install fmusdk, which requires one of Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 (VS8), 2008 (VS9), 2010 (VS10), 2012 (VS11), 2013 (VS12) or 2015 (VS14).

### Output:

`Results names and types: [('time', '<f8'), ('int_out', '<i4'), ('bool_out', '?')]`

### Expected:

I expected that `res` contained the output variable `string_out`.

### Using debug_logging:

I realised that `fmi2GetString` is **never** called, so it wouldn't be possible for the output to have the values of `string_out`. **Because of this I'm not sure if FMPy supports TypeDefinitions String or not.**

### System details:

`Python version: 3.7.3`

`FMPy version: 0.2.10`

Comment: Welcome to SO, What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) wherever required. Also please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have updated my question with the results I obtained so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are only supported as parameters (as of FMPy 0.2.10). If you need Strings as input or output you can build a custom simulation loop and use the `fmu.setString()` and `fmu.getString()` functions directly.

You can use the [custom_input.py example](https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy/blob/master/fmpy/examples/custom_input.py) as a starting point.